# Why does 背く sound like そむふ in this sentence?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

The clip and subtitles:

http://clyp.it/fmzowhxt
組織の命令に**背く**という事は どういう事か お前は わかってない！

So why is 背く being pronounced like that? I don't hear a く at all and hear a ふ instead.

Also, maybe the following is related(if not, I'll remove it and put it in its own question):

http://clyp.it/g01r22ei
自宅からウィルスを送ってたら、先走った刑事にウィルスが揃う前に捕まっちまうところだった。
I'm hearing おくfってたら instead of of おくってたら

http://clyp.it/hv3yjmeo
バトー！　ナナオはそこを経由して分割したウィルスを送ってきてる
Similarly I'm hearing おくfってきて(And no ～る, but I guess that's a question for another day.)

Edit: Revised to clarify that I'm not hearing a full mora but just an 'f' sound in 送fって. I would describe it as a single syllable "okf", but the last time I tried to describe Japanese in terms of syllables(yak'sok'), I was chastised and felt great shame..

Comment: 「そむく」「おくってたら」「おくってきてる」にしか聞こえませんが。。。

Comment: I _think_ that what might be happening is that you're hearing a strongly-aspirated く as a ふ.

Comment: The last vowel in /somuꜜku/ is a high vowel following a downstep, so I think it could it be devoiced, like [somɯkʰ].  But the sound clip is pretty fast, and I'm not sure I can transcribe how it's pronounced accurately.  (I can't figure out how to download the file to slow it down or analyze it.)

Comment: Perhaps you're listening them too sensitively.

Comment: Really cool way of sharing a sample to get feedback. Love it!

Comment: @snailboat I see a download link on the right, above all the sharing buttons. If that's not working for you, here's a mirror on mediafire - https://www.mediafire.com/folder/9vo4otodzxhg2/jse-16081.

Comment: By the way, words like 学生 where a vowel is regularly entirely omitted (gak'sei) are relatively common, but for whatever reason the vowel is still thought of as being there *psychologically*, even if it's completely gone phonetically speaking.  Sometimes there is a trace in terms of coarticulation: /t/ becomes [t͡s] before /u/, even if that /u/ is completely deleted (e.g. 月 /tuki/ realized as [t͡s̥ɯki] or [t͡ski]).  Some linguists do talk about "syllables" but it's possible to explain this while talking about morae only--see *The Phonology of Japanese*, Labrune 2012 for some discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a speaker pronounce `く`, speakers breathe out the air because of the vowel `u`.

It is *not impossible* to hear that a speaker pronunce `く` as `く(ふ)` or just `ふ` in some situations.

But it's certain that `く` is written `ku` in Romaji and it doesn't have multiple moras.